# How can I parse different types of objects from JSON?

Tags: unity, savegame, data, json

I'm trying to save the player's inventory as a JSON data but I'm having a problem. I have a class `Sword` which extends an abstract class `Weapon` which extends another abstract class called `Item`. This is what JSON file looks like with the Sword and Armor objects in it:

```
[
    {
        "category": {
            "type": "Weapon",
            "subtype": "Sword"
        },
        "id": 0,
        "value": 1,
        "name": "Wooden Sword",
        "description": "Sword made out of wood",
        "slug": "wooden_sword",
        "stats": {
            "wear": 100,
            "damage": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "type": "Armor",
            "subtype": "Helmet"
        },
        "id": 1337,
        "value": 1,
        "name": "Steel Helmet",
        "description": "Whatever...",
        "slug": "steel_helmet",
        "stats": {
            "wear": 100,
            "defence": 5,
            "vitality": 3,
            "dexterity": -1
        }
    }
]
```

How can I parse these objects into their respective C# objects, putting the first entry into a `Sword` object and the second one into a `Helmet` object. There will be other types of objects in there too, so it's not limited on these two.

Comment: _"I have a class Sword which extends abstract class Weapon which extends another abstract class Item."_ Unrelated to your issue, but... what will you do when you'll want to use a Shield (presumably an 'Armor') as a weapon ("Shield bash")? What will happen when you'll want to use your sword as a defense ("Parry")? Take a look at [Composition over inheritance](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=composition+over+inheritance) before going too deep into your objects hierarchy.

Comment: That's a really good advice, thank you. I'll certainly look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Directly converting these objects using JSONUtil won't work in this case.

What you could do instead is parse it into an intermediate data-structure first. Create a `struct` which directly mimics the structure of that JSON code (with a `category` variable which is another struct with the fields `type` and `subtype`).

You can then use the data in that structure to instantiate the actual objects of the correct types.